# How can I check the power settings in Centos 6.5?

Tags: linux, redhat, centos6

I have a headless server running Centos 6.5. Our consultant has asked that I ensure that the power settings are set up for maximum performance as opposed to balanced or energy saving.

How can I check this setting or adjust its configuration?

I know that gnome has power settings in a GUI, but I don't have a desktop environment installed regardless.

Comment: "Our consultant has asked that I ensure that the power settings are set up for maximum performance as opposed to balanced or energy saving."

Sounds like your consultant has his head in Windows land and you should take what he says with a grain of salt. :)

Comment: Do you have more details?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends...

Do you know anything about the hardware and its BIOS settings? That's where I'd check first.

Outside of that, you can modify the system's `tuned-adm` performance profile. [See the chart here](https://serverfault.com/questions/458339/overriding-default-scheduler-for-blkio-requests-in-cgroups/458342#458342). (see the CPU governor)