# Understanding CPU Throttle

Tags: linux, central-processing-unit, cpu-usage, electrical-power, resource-management

```
kernel /vmlinuz-2.6.32-379.22.1.lve1.2.17.el6.x86_64 ro root=UUID=7cb0b445-0f63-4ef1-ab73-93c114d8ef6c rd_NO_LUKS rd_NO_LVM LANG=en_US.UTF-8 rd_NO_MD SYSFONT=latarcyrheb-sun16 crashkernel=auto  KEYBOARDTYPE=pc KEYTABLE=us rd_NO_DM rhgb quiet nohz=off intel_idle.max_cstate=0 processor.max_cstate=0 idle=mwait
```

and

```
cat /proc/acpi/processor/CPU0/throttling
state count:             8
active state:            T0
state available: T0 to T7
states:
   *T0:                  100%
    T1:                  88%
    T2:                  75%
    T3:                  63%
    T4:                  50%
    T5:                  38%
    T6:                  25%
    T7:                  13%

ls /proc/acpi/processor/CPU0/
./  ../  info  limit  throttling
```

This means I have completely removed any form of idle to the CPU Xeon 5520, right?

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: CentOS 6 but with a modded kernel.

Answer (score 1):

If this is a RHEL-like system and running EL6 or similar, just use the tuned-adm framework's utilities to set the CPU governor to "Performance".

```
tuned-adm profile latency-performance
```

This was partially answered in one of your previous questions at: [Disabling CPU management](https://serverfault.com/questions/446750/disabling-cpu-management/446755#446755)

Since this is a Nehalem system, you may also want to disable C-states at the BIOS level. What type of hardware is this?

Comment: Not sure about the hardware. I would have to check.