# difference between taskset and cpuset

Tags: central-processing-unit, performance-tuning, latency, multi-core

I'm trying to reduce the latency of my linux network application. I've learned that there are two tools for "binding" a program to particular CPU core: taskset and cpuset.

1. Which one should I prefer? Are they equivalent on a lower level?
2. (the disposition) My application has single thread and is supposed to process single tcp connection (no reconnect) over fast LAN network with the least possible latency. Am I on the right way?

Comment: Did you read their respective man pages?

Comment: Have you run detailed profiling so that you are sure that it is the Linux networking part that causes the latency, and not the application?

Comment: Which OS/distribution/version/kernel are you running?

Comment: Also, what type of hardware is involved? Server make/model, CPU specifications, networking infrastructure...

Answer (score 15):

**Taskset** is for binding a process to one or more CPUs; essentially specifying *where* it can run at initial execution or while it's running. If using RHEL/CentOS on modern server equipment, `numactl` is recommended over `taskset`.

**Cpuset/cset** is for CPU shielding and is a framework build around Linux cgroups. Cset was never popular on certain distributions (like RHEL) because there are other tools available for process management.

The first command below creates a shield that would limit the operating system's tasks to CPU cores 0 and 8. The second would move your current shell session to the CPU shield specified, resulting in an isolation of system and user processes.

```
# cset shield --cpu 1-7,9-15 --kthread=on
# cset proc --move --pid=$$ --threads --toset=user
```

There are other things to possibly check for and tune before you go down the path of binding processes to CPUs; interrupts (`irqbalance` partial disablement), power-saving settings, system scheduler, I/O elevators, realtime policy ([`chrt`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/chrt.1.html)).

See: [Low latency TCP settings on Ubuntu](https://serverfault.com/questions/623780/low-latency-tcp-settings-on-ubuntu/623792#623792)

Here's a (*convoluted*) example of an application wrapper that selects a core, stops irqbalance, starts it and blacklists the selected core, then executes ./your_program with [SCHED_FIFO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16730634/560492) and priority 99 on the selected core.

```
Core=5
CoreMask=`echo "16 o 2 $Core ^ p" | dc`
service irqbalance stop
  until [ "`service irqbalance status`" = "irqbalance is stopped" ] ; do sleep 1 ; done
IRQBALANCE_ONESHOT=1 IRQBALANCE_BANNED_CPUS=${CoreMask} irqbalance
sleep 1
  until [ "`service irqbalance status`" = "irqbalance is stopped" ] ; do sleep 1 ; done
numactl --physcpubind=${Core} --localalloc chrt -f 99 ./your_program
```

Comment: Note, its possible for an application to reset its affinities when using `taskset`. If you use cpuset its not possible to alter your affinities from what the cpuset grants you.

Comment: And `numactl`??

Comment: Same, both programs call the same underlying system call `sched_setaffinity`.